# I need a clarification about the local disk on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, elementary-os

I was using Windows 7 and in My Computer I had 2 local disks `C:` and `D:`.

On Elementary I only see a File System (if i'm not mistaken).

Has Linux combined these 2 into one called File System?

Comment: Are your C: & D: drives two physical hard drives or two partitions on one hard drive, when you use Windows 7?

Comment: @Fred I'm not sure if it's two physical or partitions, is there a way to check it ??? I've been using Windows 7 for a couple years, and I change to Linux just 2 days ago.

Comment: Just to make sure, is it the same computer?

Comment: @techraf ofc it is.

Comment: Possible the worst question title I have seen on U&L (so far).

Comment: @Anthon POSSIBLY the worst comment I've ever read so far

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Linux and UNIX don't have drive letters.  There is one partition (a drive letter in windows, more or less) that is the "root" partition.  The root partition is called "/".  Any other partitions you use are mounted to directories somewhere below the root partition.

For example, on this system, the third partition on my drive is the root partition.  The second one is mounted at /var.  The fifth is mounted at /tmp, and the sixth is mounted at /home.  I have a partition on another hard disk that is mounted at /home/spauldo/Videos, because I can easily run out of space doing video editing.

To the user, you can't tell what partition you're currently using unless you look.  It's all transparent.  You can see what partitions you're using by using the `mount` command.

If you think there is space you haven't used, there are commands that will tell you what is available.  `fdisk` and `gpart` can read partition tables and tell you what is on each disk.  You likely have a partition set up for swap space that won't be mounted, and if Windows is still on your machine you may or may not have its partitions mounted as well (depends on your distro's install program).  `df -h` is handy for seeing how much free space you have.

Bear in mind you'll have a lot of "virtual" partitions for various system-related things, like /proc, /dev, and /sys.  Those aren't real - they just provide a file-based interface to kernel internals.

If you didn't use all your disks when you installed, it's relatively easy to add them in later.  See the documentation for your distribution for more info on how to do that - the GUI tools vary from distro to distro.